# Why you should never use synchronized on Optional java object

Tags: java, java-8, option-type, synchronized, design-principles

I m learning about java optional wrapper, to do so I m reading the following [tutorial](https://dzone.com/articles/using-optional-correctly-is-not-optional)

however I have a simple question that is not answered in the article: in **item 25: Avoid Using Identity-Sensitive Operations on Optionals** they are mentioning to **NEVER** use an optional object in a synchronized way like this:

```
Optional<Product> product = Optional.of(new Product());

synchronized(product) {

    ...

}
```

but there is no explanation why, so please would any one here  explain to me why this is a bad  practice ???

Comment: @HadiJ nope, that is not it...

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/doc-files/ValueBased.html

Comment: Thanks @Amadan :) now I will read about value-based classes to know more :)

Comment: the real answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47545351/1059372)

Comment: @Eugene I also found [this](https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/tag/java8/RSPEC-3436)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because

> [value-based classes] are freely substitutable when equal, meaning that
>   interchanging any two instances x and y that are equal according to
>   `equals()` in any computation or method invocation should produce no
>   visible change in behavior"

[Source](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/doc-files/ValueBased.html) (Oracle)

You can not freely substitute X and Y if there is an intrinsic lock on one of them, since doing so may produce a change in behaviour.

Comment: thank you so much for this answer, I found [this article](https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/tag/java8/RSPEC-3436) this also explain the same thing with an example for all who are  new  to java 8 like me